# When did R begin supporting here-document-like functionality?

Tags: r, multilinestring

Just over a year ago, I searched online for here-document (or similar) capability in R.  I didn't find any indication of it.  Now, it's among the first things that pop up in a google search -- for example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#R).  I'm not sure whether this is because it is a relatively new capability, or a capability that was present before but not well-known.

**When did this capability became available?**

**If it was available for much more than a year, was it simply relatively unknown?**

(If so, then I was just not searching properly back then).

---

**Code example**

In R, one can do

```
query <-
"
  SELECT FirstName,
         LastName,
         Address
  INTO tAllBobs
  FROM tContacts
  WHERE FirstName = 'Bob'
  ORDER BY LastName
"
```

In VBA, one has to do:

```
query = _
  "SELECT FirstName,      " & _
  "       LastName,       " & _
  "       Address         " & _
  "INTO tAllBobs          " & _
  "FROM tContacts         " & _
  "WHERE FirstName = 'Bob' " & _
  "ORDER BY LastName      "
```

The string delimiters and line continuation syntax
makes the code difficult to modify and reformat.  Even
adding the single quotes around 'Bob' (as I did above) disrupts the formatting.
Larger revisions would wreak havoc and require intense re-editing.

This is why I was interested in when here-document
capability was supported in R.

Comment: I've been using `read.table(text = "some text")` for years, now learning it is called "here-document".

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking when `textConnection` was introduced to R, it seems about 21 years ago:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/968826560933840f10919b81a22762c1e7eacee1

Admittedly it's never been easy to search for it -- I only learned it myself in the past 12-18 months, I'd say.

As for Wikipedia, that section has been there since 2012:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Here_document&oldid=492468681

Comment: I'm not an R coder, but I was searching for here-document capability as part of a environmental scan of information for a thought piece on data IO practices.  I could be wrong, but based on the Wikipedia section cited in my question, it might be more than just `textConnection` (though I did browse the help information for that).  I think it may boil down to when `textConnection` started to accept strings.

Comment: Regardless of whether that is the key ingredient, I was also wondering when the here-document capability became well-known.  It seems odd that I couldn't find it just over a year ago, but that could just have been either me or a dearth of links to the information online at the time.